# Matching the last digits of a number in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file in which there are a lot of GUIDs mentioned like this

```
Dlg1={929EC5C7-0A40-4BE4-8F0A-60C3CB4A62A7}-SdWelcome-0
```

I wanted to replace the last eight digits of these GUIDs with the last eight digits of a new GUID which is already  generated using a tool. What I have tried so follows.

Read the last eight digits of the generated GUID like this:

```
$GUID =~ /[0-9a-fA-F]{8}/;
```

Assign it to a new variable like:

```
$newGUID = $1;
```

Now try to replace this with the old GUID inside the file:

```
if ($line =~ /^.* {(.*)}/) {
    $line =~ s/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}}/$newGUID/;
}
```

But it does not seem to be working. It replaces the last eight digits of the old GUID with 32 digits of the new GUID. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should probably look into [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html), it is much better suited to this task.

Comment: Then `$newGUID =$1` is probably what is not working. Can you print/debug this value and see what is it?

Comment: Where are your parenthesis for `$1` ?? :)

Comment: Your "read" of the last 8 digits is incorrect. You will read the first 8 digits, unless you anchor the string to the end of the numbers somehow. You also do not capture any string with that regex (using parentheses), so `$1` is empty. Instead of showing fragments of your code which makes no sense, show your entire code, compilable, with input and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

> it replaces the last 8 digits of old GUID with 32 digits of new GUID , any ideas how to achieve it.

You now have this:

```
$line =~s/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}}/$newGUID/;
```

You say that replaces the last eight characters of your GUID with the entire 32 digit new GUID. That means your finding and replacing the right characters, but what you're replacing it with is wrong.

What is `$newGUID` equal to? Is it an entire 32 digit GUID? If so, you need to pull off the last 8 characters.

Two things I would recommend.

- If you are using a hexadecimal number in your regular expression, use `[[:xdigit:]]` and not `[0-9a-fA-F]`. Although both are pretty much equivalent. Using `:xdigit:` is cleaner and it's easier to understand.
- In Perl, we love regular expressions. Heck, Perl regular expression syntax has invaded and found homes in almost all other programming languages. However, regular expressions can be difficult to get right and test. They can also be difficult to understand too. However, sometimes there are better ways of doing something besides a regular expression that's cleaner and easier to undertstand.

In this case, you should use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) rather than regular expressions. You know exactly what you want, and you know the location in the string. The `substr` command would make what you're doing easier to understand and even cleaner:

```
use constant {
    GUID_RE => qr/^[[:xdigit:]]{8}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}$/,
};

my $old_guid = '929EC5C7-0A40-4BE4-8F0A-60C3CB4A62A7';
my $new_guid = 'oooooooo-oooo-oooo-oooo-ooooXXXXXXXX';

# Regular expressions are great for verifying formats!
if ( not $old_guid =~ GUID_RE ) {
    die qq(Old GUID "$new_guid" is not a GUID string);
}

if ( not $new_guid =~ GUID_RE ) { # Yes, I know this will die in this case
    die qq(New GUID "$new_guid" is not a GUID string);
}

# Easy to understand, I'm removing the last eight characters of $old_guid
# and appending the last eight digits of $new_guid

my $munged_guid = substr( $old_guid, 0, -8 ) . substr( $new_guid, -8 );

say $munged_guid;  # Prints 929EC5C7-0A40-4BE4-8F0A-60C3XXXXXXX
```

I'm using regular expressions to verify that the GUID are correctly formatted which is a great task for regular expressions.

I define a GUID_RE constant. You can look to see how it's defined and verify if it's in the correct format (12 hex digits, 4 hex digits, 4 hex digits, and 12 hex digits all separated by dashes).

Then, I can use that `GUID_RE` constant in my program, and it's easy to see what I'm doing. Is my GUID actually in the  GUID_ID format?

Using `substr` instead of regular expressions make it easy to see exactly what I am doing. I am removing the last eight characters off of `$old_guid` and appending the last eight characters of `$new_guid`.

Again, your immediate issue is that your `s/.../.../` is finding the right characters, but your substitution string isn't correct. However, this isn't the best use for regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you're not correctly setting `$1` to the last eight digits (if it's coming from that regex, it would match the first eight digits and isn't setting any groups). You could instead try something like `$newGUID = substr($GUID, -8);`.  I also think something like $GUIDTail makes more sense for the variable since it doesn't store an entire GUID.

Also, at the moment you're eating the closing curly brace. You should either include that in newGuid/guidTail, include it in the `s///` call, or change the curly in the match to `(?=\})` (which represents match this but don't include it in the match).

P.S.: You're making the assumption there that's there's only one GUID on the line. You may want to tack a global modifier to the match if there's any chance of multiple GUIDs (or otherwise disambiguating which one you want to modify, but this will just replace the first one).

Comment: Thanks hwnd (made the same edit I did, but faster); there was an errant $ in the 0 width matching assertion).

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you , i have used substr and it seems to be working , i have one more doubt i f i have to replace whole of the GUID with new one what should be the matching expression , i am relatively new to perl so dont know much about these .

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small code snippet that demonstrates the principle I think you are after. First off, I start with a given string, and take the last 8 characters of it and store it in a new variable, `$insert`. Then I perform a somewhat strict substitution on the input data (here in the internal file handle `DATA`, which is convenient when demonstrating), and print the altered string.

The regex in the substitution looks for curly brackets `{ ... }` with a mixture of hex digits `[:xdigit:]` and dashes `\-` between them (`[[:xdigit:]\-]+`), followed by 8 hex digits. The `\K` escape allows us to "keep" the matched string before it, so all we need to do is insert our stored string, and replace the closing curly bracket.

If you wish to try this on a file, change `<DATA>` to `<>` and run it like so:

```
perl script.pl input
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $new = "929EC5C7-0A40-4BE4-8F0A-1234567890";
my $insert = substr($new, -8);

while (<DATA>) {
    s/\{[[:xdigit:]\-]+\K[[:xdigit:]]{8}\}/$insert}/i;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Dlg1={929EC5C7-0A40-4BE4-8F0A-60C3CB4A62A7}-SdWelcome-0
```

**Output:**

```
Dlg1={929EC5C7-0A40-4BE4-8F0A-60C334567890}-SdWelcome-0
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs , would it be possible to give some directions for how to replace whole of the old gUID with new one inside the file .

Comment: Replacing the whole GUID is easier, then you just remove everything and insert `{$new}`.